# Javascript error on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, safari

I'm having some problems with javascript on desktop safari, on mobile is working fine.

When I try to run:

```
return Math.trunc(num * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);
```

I'm getting on console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Math.trunc(num * Math.pow(10, 2))')
```

Any idea why can it be? On the rest of browsers is working perfectly and I have no clue why (I've never worked with safari).

Comment: Is rounding towards zero strictly required, i.e., is the rounding of negative numbers expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.trunc` was added in ES2015 (June 2015). Apparently the JavaScript engine in the version of Safari you're using doesn't have it yet.

You could polyfill it if it's missing:

```
if (!Math.trunc) {
    Object.defineProperty(Math, "trunc", {
        value: function(val) {
            return val < 0 ? Math.ceil(val) : Math.floor(val);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) it's in Safari 7.1, although we don't really know what version of the browser is OP trying.

Comment: Safari => 7.1 should have it.

Comment: ok, is there any alternative for that fucntion? I saw `Math.Floor` but is not exactly the same

Comment: @HectorLandete well you could do it through biwise arithmetic `num | 0`, however be aware that this will not work with big numbers. More specifically anything larger than `2^31 - 1` (2147483647). You can also do string manipulation by chopping off the dot and everything after. Or you can try a library that does maths.

Comment: @HectorLandete: I've added a polyfill to the answer. *Fairly* sure that's correct, but double-check it...

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: @SSA can you tell me which Safari version doesn't support Math function?

Comment: @Purni - ?? The comment from SSA above says any version >= 7.1 should have `Math.trunc` ([MDN says 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc#browser_compatibility), but...). So unless you're using a **really** out of date version of Safari, it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

What about `return ~~(num * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);`?

The `~~` operator seems to be a good replacement for `Math.trunc()`

Comment: ...except that it will fail for large numbers, as it requires a round trip through a signed 32-bit integer. And if that's not an issue, there's a dramatically simpler way: `num | 0`.